# Show a union of Noetherian rings is not Noetherian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

For every $n$ we define $R_n=\mathbb{Z}[2^{1/2}, \dots, n^{1/n}]$, viewed as a subring of the real numbers. How can we prove that $R=\bigcup_n R_n$ is not Noetherian?

I think we need to find a sequence of ideals which does not stabilizes, but I can't find such a sequence.

Comment: Have you tried something like $I_1 = \langle 2^{1/2} \rangle, I_2 = \langle 2^{1/2}, 3^{1/3} \rangle, I_3 = \langle 2^{1/2}, 3^{1/3}, 5^{1/5} \rangle,...$?

Comment: So the title should be "union of rings is *not* Noetherian"?

Comment: $I_2$ contains $2,3$ and hence it is the whole ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ideal $I_n=\langle2^{\frac12}, (2^2)^{\frac1{2^2}}, \cdots,(2^n)^{\frac1{2^n}}\rangle$ in $R$.

Let $v$ be an extension of the $2$-adic valuation of $\Bbb Z$ to $R$. ($v$ can be any extension of the $2$-adic valuation of $\Bbb Z$ to $\bar{\Bbb Q}$ then restricted to $R$.)

Since the sequence $\frac12, \frac2{2^2}, \frac 3{2^3},\cdots,$ decreases to $0$ and $\min\{v(a)\mid a\in I_n\}=\frac n{2^n}$, the sequence $I_1, I_2, I_3, \cdots,$ does not stabilize.