# An idea for proof of Hilbert basis Theorem based on direct sums of rings

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification

Here is a rough sketch of a proof idea I have for showing Hilbert's basis theorem:

Goal: Show that the polynomial ring of a noetherian ring is noetherian

Step-1: For a given $n$, the sub ring of nth degree polynomial who only has leading term non zero is Noetherian(*). So, for instance the constant term is Noetherian, the polynomials with only degree on terms are Noetherian and so on.

*: For constants, it would be $R$, it's Noetherian by given

For degree $1$, we can see it trivially , and by induction we can show for general $n$

Step-2: We can consider a general n-th degree Polynomial as being constructed by a direct sum of the type of polynomial subrings mentioned in-1. Now finite direct sum of these type of rings till nth degree would be Noetherian, call this $U_n$. And, a general polynomial ring would be isomorphic to the $\cup_{n} U_n$ and hence also Noetherian.

Is this right or not?

Comment: I tried to explaijn more @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: How so? Consider the a ring of form $R_n =\{ a_n x^n| a_n \in R \}$ this is Noetherian, right? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Answer (score 1):

In the current state, unfortunately, it fails. As Noetherian-ness is not generally preserved under unions. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589316/show-a-union-of-noetherian-rings-is-not-noetherian)